# Facebook & Jquery - Share to show

Tags: jquery, facebook, jquery-ui

How to create a Jquery function that works with Facebook API so that the content only is shown if the user has shared it?

Comment: Those of you closing this question: I think this is the best quality you can expect on the Facebook tag.  Is there something about this question that is not understandable?  The OP wants a jQuery function that will show content only if the user has shared said content.

Comment: i was hesitant to flag it, instead of just downvoting it, but there is a flag for low quality pending improvement. I don't think it's really understandable so thats why I flagged it. There are multiple ways to share content through FB. Like button, sharer URL, SDK. All very different methods, more info here is warranted.

Comment: @Robert I agree with Ilya that this is *way* too hazy even for the Facebook tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the Javascript SDK to publish stories, show the content in the callback response when a user shares content successfully:

```
FB.ui(
 {
method: 'feed',
name: 'Google',
link: 'http://www.google.com/',
picture: 'http://google.com/xyz.jpg',
caption: 'Google Logo',
description: 'Search away'
 },
function(response) {
if (response && response.post_id) {
  // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
  // e.g.
  $("#some_div").show();
} 
});
```

Note: Make sure you have loaded the Facebook JS SDK and jQuery.

More about JS SDK [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)